# How to apply Masking to complex CNN+LSTM network architecture?

Tags: keras

I have a sequential model which processes videos (sequence of images).
My model looks like this:

```
Time = 0    Time = 1    ....    Time = t
  im@0         im@1     ....       im@t
    |            |                   |
   CNN          CNN     ....        CNN
    |            |                   |
   RNN--------->RNN---->....------->RNN
                                     |
                               some prediction
```

It works well on invariant-length sequences. But I'd like it to accept variable length sequences. As we know, in keras, Masking layer could help us to handle this case but is not supported by all layers. I have a rather complex CNN architecture so it seems no way I can use a Masking layer before CNN.

Is there any way to resolve this?

[**EDIT**]
I've found that the TimeDistributed Wrapper could make it possible for applying mask. But I don't know if my implementation is right:

```
cnn = make_basenet(...)            # make backbone network
cnn = TimeDistributed(cnn)         # wrap the cnn with TimeDistributed

seq = Sequential()                 # CNN + LSTM
seq.add(Masking(input_shape=(...)) # Masking for TimeDistributed CNN
seq.add(cnn)                       # add CNN
seq.add(Masking())                 # **This is necessary**
seq.add(LSTM(...))                 # add LSTM
```

If I omit the Masking layer before LSTM, error will be raised. But it works if I add this Masking layer. I'm wondering if I implemented my model in a right way?